# Side-effects of declaring node inbuilt packages explicitly on package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, require, node-modules

I just tried putting the followings on my package.json deps list:

```
"http": "*",
"path": "*",
"fs": "*"
```

I ran the `npm install` and found that NPM downloaded these dependencies. Now I am curious to know

1. Are these downloads in the `node_modules` same as the packages originally inbuilt with node.js?
2. How does the `require` module in the node treat these modules i.e. will it return the node.js inbuilt implementation or the implementation present on the `node_modules` folder on the root directory.
3. Is my application going to behave differently because of this?

Answer (score -1):

These packages are standart libraries and there is no need to install them under npm. Just:

```
var http = require('http');
```

All of them can be founded in [API Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/)

1. They download latest version that matches your npm & node versions.
2. Require will choose files from node_modules/
3. If backwards will be broken, than behaviors can differs, but node.js try to avoid change standard lib API.

Comment: yea right, that I am aware of... but I am interested in side-effects of declaring them explicitly on package.json..